How to programmatically disable or enable "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in Windows 10 and Windows 11?
This Super User answer explains well what the feature is, but what matters is that it can be enabled using a checkbox in a subwindow of intl.cpl:

How can I accomplish this programmatically?

As I wrote this question, I noticed that I appear to have already answered this question a few years ago at learn.microsoft.com:
#!/usr/bin/env -S pwsh

#```PS1
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
#Requires -PSEdition Core
#Requires -Version 7.4
#```

#Reg2CI (c) 2022 by Roger Zander

If ([OperatingSystem]::IsWindows() -Eq $True) {
    If((Test-Path -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage') -NE $True) { New-Item "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" -Force }
    New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage' -Name 'ACP' -Value 65001 -PropertyType 'String' -Force
    New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage' -Name 'OEMCP' -Value 65001 -PropertyType 'String' -Force
    New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage' -Name 'MACCP' -Value 65001 -PropertyType 'String' -Force
}

Presumably, I put this through github.com/rzander/Reg2CI/blob/master/README.md (as this SU answer explains).
